# GetAccessControl throws UnauthorizedAccessException accessing SystemData directory

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, readonly, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I've been working with C#, specifically the UWP/WPF framework(s), editing some of the subdirectories of `C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\SystemData` for the purposes of editing and deleting lock screen images stored in `C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\SystemData\\ID\\ReadOnly`.

I originally had just manually changed the permissions of the `ProgramData` directory and then the `SystemData` directory, however whenever the system modifies files inside the `SystemData` directory, its permissions are reset. (I want the final product of my program to be scheduled to run periodically, hence I wouldn't be able to do this manually every time.) Simply calling: `Directory.GetAccessControl("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\SystemData");`
yields `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'`.

The default permissions of the directory do not allow me to even read the attributes of the directory or access its files without modifying its permissions as an administrator. Since I can do so manually (to edit permissions to give myself full control) I assume there's some way to do so in C#. My `app.manifest` does have `requireAdministrator` as the `requestedExecutionLevel` and I'm currently not using any impersonation, with the current `WindowsIdentity` showing as `LAPTOP-ID\\USERNAME`.

How can I perform these changes when I can't even get access control to the directory I need to edit the permissions of?

Comment: For setting  lock screen images, you could use [`LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.setimagefileasync#Windows_System_UserProfile_LockScreen_SetImageFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_) to approach, why you want to modify the folder access authorization ?

Comment: I've been using `LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync` however I've found that the way the lock screen works is that there are subdirectories of `ReadOnly` named `LockScreen_A`, `LockScreen_B`, etc. which when the lock screen is set (using the aforementioned function or manually in settings), 4 image files are created in the directory--the original and 3 resized versions. Only when the user logs out a 5th image then is created which is the lock screen image. When calling the aforementioned function it only sets the first 4 images hence I need to delete the 5th I believe before calling the function

Answer (score 0):

> When calling the aforementioned function it only sets the first 4 images hence I need to delete the 5th I believe before calling the function.

Your description is correct. Please check the following screenshot, the default lockscreen image was stored in `LockScreen_o` folder. Every time you call the above method(`LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync`), it will create a new folder and name the folder name in a-z order. It means that each lockscreen image has its own folder, So you have no need delete the 5th image that created after lock screen. And the default owner of folder is 
**System** that could not be modified with uwp code.

[image]

I use the following code to set lockscreen it works for each image.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: My relevant code is as follows:
`StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(files[r.Next(0, files.Count)]);
await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);`
(the rest is here, and yes it still has a number of other unrelated issues: https://pastebin.com/4iZ53aRu).
I know `file.Path` is valid however I'm still finding that only `LockScreen_A` is being changed, and still only the first 4 images are being changed to the new image specified by `file`. The 5th does not even change after logging off/locking/restarting my computer

Comment: The code in the case reply only works in uwp. I  checked your code that is wpf project. Actually, I didn't know your issue clearly.

Comment: So I tried to test the code provided above just to see if I could get it producing some result to provide me some insight, however in my blank UWP application `Windows.System.UserProfile` does not contain `LockScreen` for some odd reason, even though it exists in my WPF application. What would be the cause of this?

Comment: There is no such `LockScreen` [known folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders) in uwp, uwp only provide method to change the lockscreen and does not provide the path of the lockscreen folder.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but I was referring to the `LockScreen` class within (i.e. `Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen`) which I don't appear to have access to in UWP but I had access to it in WPF. I have access to all of the other classes in `Windows.System.UserProfile` it appears except `LockScreen` and possibly one or two others